# Make a List of numbers formatted with commas from multiple cells to one cell

Tags: vba, excel

For starters I have limited experience with VBA and was hoping to accomplish this task with built in excel functions, unfortunately without success. Here is the problem:

I have multiple cells with number values in them (lets say 3 cells each with a value of 1000) and I need that converted to one cell with those same multiple values (on top of each other like a list) and be able to have them formatted with commas at thousands places.

I have been successful at putting them in one cell by using an ampersand and the char(10) function along with formatting to wrap text.

However, now I cannot format with commas. Can this be done without VBA? If not some direction for writing a function would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add the exact formula you used to putting them in one cell? Add more details to your question like sample data and expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Without **VBA**

```
=TEXT(A1,"#,##0")&CHAR(10)&TEXT(B1,"#,##0")&CHAR(10)&TEXT(C1,"#,##0")
```

For example:

[image]